# Pass Data from Partial View with same model in Foreach loop to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, partial

I am working on MVC3 Project where i am required to Pass data from Partial view with same model instance to controller.

The main View contains Model as 
`@model Models.Patients.PatientNewVisitModel`

```
@foreach (var item in Model.woundList)
{
   @Html.Partial("PatientNewVisitPartialView",item.Wound)                                
}
```

And Partial view contains the model as

`@model Models.Patients.PatientNewVisitModel.Wound`

which is rendered from foreach statement of main view

The controls are displayed but i am unable to get the corresponding values in controller under `PatientNewVisitModel` model.

[HttpPost]

```
   public ActionResult PatientNewVisit(PatientNewVisitModel objPatientNewVisitModel)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Please help me out for this problem

Comment: Could you show your view? Does it contain a form? How are you invoking this POST controller action?

Answer (score 0):

In Wound partial View You can do something like this:

```
@{ var index = Guid.NewGuid(); }
@Html.Hidden("Wounds.Index", index)

@Html.TextBox("Wounds[" + index + "].Property1", Model.Property1)
@Html.TextBox("Wounds[" + index + "].Property2", Model.Property2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback How i can write the above code for @Html.TextBoxfor

Comment: What's the difference? I think you cannot, but I'm not sure